# How do I use the fontWeight or fontVariant in CSSProperties to access a font variant in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, google-fonts

I'm trying to use the variants available in this google font (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ruda) inside a React Native app. I get the standard font to load just fine, but it's the kind of font that contains all the variants in the same `ttf`, and I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Snack here:
https://snack.expo.dev/@ftoldghost/variable-font-test

I've tried messing with `fontWeight` but either it does nothing, or it makes it (for example) bold while overriding `fontFamily` and reverting back to a default font.

I've also tried using `fontVariant` but I can't figure out a syntax that doesn't throw errors. Some of the errors are things like `Type '"Semi-Bold"[]' is not assignable to type 'FontVariant[]'.` in the IDE or `java.lang.String cannot be cast to abi42_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray`. That's with trying to set it (as I've seen recommended in this way:

`fontVariant: ['Semi-Bold']`

What the correct way to use variants of a self-contained `ttf` like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using google fonts you are not able to use `fontWeight`
you can simply download all the variants of fonts from google and use them as

`fontFamily:'Ruda-Bold'` or `fontFamily:'Ruda-SemiBold'`